# Rails Multi-Step Form without Wizard Gem

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, multi-step

I have a Rails 3.2.14 app which collects call data.  The new and edit action form is pretty long on one page.  I'm looking to implement a multistep form that uses JS/client side processing to move along the steps.  I've looked at the [Wicked Gem](https://github.com/schneems/wicked) as a way to do multi-step forms however I don't need the stateful configuration and don't want to be updating the call record with each step.  I just need a clean way to split the form into steps and give an indication of the current step.

I've looked into Fuelx and its Wizard component for forms but would like to see if there are any other JS modules out there to create multi-step forms in Rails.

I realize this question may be a bit vague so feel free to edit or provide feedback.  If any of this is not clear, please let me know.  Just looking for suggestions or techniques on how to make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trial and error I was able to use [Fuelux](http://exacttarget.github.io/fuelux/) to implement a multi step form within my app.  Eventually I will look into building a multistep form which records the state of the record maybe using the [Wicked Wizard Gem](https://github.com/schneems/wicked) as a means for defining steps.  But for now Fuelux's Wizard component works great.

Comment: shakycode as of today what would you recommend to go with? I've checked a bunch of solutions but couldn't decide which one to choose.

Comment: I used the Fuelux Wizard JS to do the multistep form.  Granted it doesn't track state like a step controller but it works pretty well